# Compatibility between Fortran Software and Windows 8?

Tags: windows, fortran, compatibility

I would like to know if the Fortran Software (example: Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE) is compatible with Windows 8 Operational System?

I tryed to install Visual Studio (2008 and 2010 versions) with Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 11.1 at Windows 8 OS, but I can´t integrate into Visual Studio (When I create a new project, there is no "Intel(R) Fortran" option. I think the problem is the compatibility with Windows 8. In Windows 7 OS it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that your version of Intel Fortran may be too old for your o/s, but I'm sure that Intel's fulsome online documentation will reveal the (in-)validity of my suspicion if you search well.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 hasn't been tested with that combination, but it should work well. See http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/troubleshooting-fortran-integration-issues-with-visual-studio/ for troubleshooting this issue. Ask in the [Intel user forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows) if you need more help

Comment: Thanks a lot. The information was usefull to solve the problem.